# Basic Kaplan-Meier survival analysis input data interpretation with discrete time periods

Tags: python, survival, kaplan-meier, discrete-time

I am trying to apply Kaplan-Meier survival analysis from the Reliability package in Python to a problem with discrete time periods, and I'm having some trouble understanding which periods to list failures and right-censored data in.

My problem input is described (with made-up data) as follows:

I have 200 people in a trial with 5 chronological Period.

100 participants completed the trial.

- 20 people died in Period 1
- 15 people died in Period 2
- 10 people died in Period 3
- 3  people died in Period 4
- 2  people died in Period 5
- the remaining 50 people survived all the periods

100 participants are still in the trial, as follows:

- 40 people were last observed in Period 1
- 20 people were last observed in Period 2
- 20 people were last observed in Period 3
- 10  people were last observed in Period 4
- 10  people were last observed in Period 5

Python's Reliability package takes as input two simple lists, `failures`, and `right_censored`.  I imagine the interpretation of the list indices is the same for other K-M implementations, but if matters, that's the one I'm using.

I made two "dummy" time-periods, "Period 0" and "Period 6" and list the participant-*counts* (indexed from 0):

`failure_count=[0,20,15,10,3,2]`

`right_censored_count=[40,20,20,10,10,50]`

As such, an item at index `i` in either of these lists has been observed through the entirety of Period `0` through `i`, inclusive.

(edit: I added details about tranforming the "count" to datapoint lists)

The *count* lists are transformed to datapoint lists as

`failures=[<0 repeated 0 times>, <1 repeated 20 times>, <2 repeated 15 times>, etc]` and `right_censored=[<0 repeated 40 times>, <1 repeated 20 times>, etc]`.

**Main Question Is this the right way to provide the input to K-M in Python Reliability?**

Sub question: Where do I put the 50 patients that survived all 5 periods?  I'm surprised that I don't get the same output from the seemingly equivalent input `failures_count=[0,20,15,10,3,2,50]` and `right_censored_count=[40,20,20,10,10,0,0]`.

Or if you can't answer that, is it the right interpretation of discrete K-M inputs in general?

Comment: The problem is one of interval censoring. If a subject "dies" in period 1, at what time do you say they died? The start or the end of the period or something else? That should inform how you handle patients who survive through period 5, but the most obvious choice is to set their event time to the end of Pd 5 and consider them censored events.

Comment: Not knowing the Python package, your inputs to the function arguments are suspect. If I wrote a survival package that took "failures" as a vector input, then I would interpret [40, 20, 20...] as meaning a subject died at time 40, a subject died at time 20, etc. But questions about Python would have to go to that other SE network.

Comment: @AdamO Apologies, you must have seen my first draft (during the one minute it was up there!) and I have added details about expanding the count lists to actual datapoint lists.

Comment: I tried the problem in R and in Python Lifelines package and found that those agree with eachother but they disagree with the Reliability package.  Furthermore, it doesn't matter to the former two whether I put the 50 survivors into the failure list or the censored list, which is what I expected.  Something goofy is going on with the Reliability package (or me).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is probably off topic. You need more details on these packages before fitting the models. I am not sure, for instance, which if any of the models are parametric models (and if they are, are they Weibull, Gumbel, Exponential?) or Cox models. In R it would be easy to point out the syntax. Making two programs agree on different software packages does not corroborate any results.

Comment: Thanks @AdamO.  Agreeming with R is helpful because there is a lot of material on its usage out there.  This video (and the previous one in the series), for example, very clearly describes the interpretation for R inputs.  So you are right, agreement on its own does not corroborate results, but I now have a more complete understanding of R inputs.